# Generating matplotlib chart in vscode isn't working

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm following the tutorial here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial

At step 10, I am not seeing an image of a graph, instead I'm seeing this text: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='survived', ylabel='fare'>

There is an option to 'change output mimetype' for that line, but only option is text/plain.